# create subject action not working. Crud

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm very new to Ruby On Rails and am having some trouble when trying to "create" a new subject.  I have all my links working but when I try to create a new subject I get an ActiveModel::Forbidden Atrributes Error.  I believe the issue is either with my routes.rb file or failure to properly set params in my Subject controller.  Also there is something confusing happening in my routes that I would love to have explained if anyone knows the theory behind it.  If, in my routes.rb file I write:

```
    get 'subjects/list' => 'subjects#list'
    get 'subjects/new => 'subjects#create'
    resources :subjects
```

Then when I go to my local host and type: localhost:3000/subjects/new, it automatically creates a new subject in localhost:3000/subjects/list.  This means my "create" action is working, just not in the way I'd like it too.  If I delete the line

```
    get 'subjects/new' => 'subjects#create'
```

from my routes.rb file, when I go to my localhost:3000/subjects/new page I get my form to submit a new subject but when I press the button it reports the error I mentioned earlier.  Here is what I have in my folders.

Subjects_Controller.rb:

```
    class SubjectsController < ApplicationController

def index
    list 
    render('list')
end

# def index
#   show
#   render('show')
# end

def list 
    @subjects = Subject.order("subjects.position ASC")
    #@subjects = Subject.all 
end 

def show 
    @subject = Subject.find(params[:id])
end

def new
    @subjects = Subject.new(:name => 'default')
end

def create 
    @subject = Subject.new(params[:subject])

    if @subject.save 

        redirect_to(:action => 'list')

    else 
        render('new')
    end




end
```

end

Here is my new.html.erb file:

```
    <%= link_to("<< Back to List", {:action => 'list'}, :class => 'back-  link') %>

    <div class="subject new">
        <h2>Create Subject</h2>

        <%= form_for(:subject, :url => {:action => 'create'}) do |f| %>

            <table summary="Subject form fields">
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <td><%= f.text_field(:name) %></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Position</th>
                    <td><%= f.text_field(:position) %></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Visible</th>
                    <td><%= f.text_field(:visible) %></td>
                </tr>
            </table>

            <div class="form-buttons">
                <%= submit_tag("Create Subject") %>
            </div>
        <% end %>
    </div>
```

Here is my routes.rb file:

```
    Rails.application.routes.draw do
    get 'subjects/list' => 'subjects#create'
    resources :subjects
```

I hope this question isn't too confusing.  Really I'm just wondering why Create Subject action is giving me the error.  I only included the bit about my subjects/list => 'subjects#create' to get some insight as to why this routing lets me create a subject, even though it's not in the way I'd like it to.  Thanks for any advice!.  I'm using rails 4.2 BTW.

Comment: (And many others; searching the web should find you a ton of info about this since it's a common mistake.)

Comment: Typically "GET subjects/list" would return the list of existing subjects. Not invoke a create. "GET subjects/new" would create a new/default Subject for user update. Remove your custom route from routes.rb. At the command line, run a "rake routes >routes.lst" then look at the routes.lst file. Put your custom route back in, then do it again, outputting to routes.lst2 or something, then compare those files.

Comment: I got my 'create' to work using strong parameters, now I'm having trouble with update but I'm guessing I just need to identify strong parameters for that as well

Answer (score 1):

> Why Create Subject action is giving me the error. `ActiveModel::Forbidden Atrributes`

Because you should use [`strong parameters`](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html) in `Rails 4.2`.

Add to bottom of `Subjects_Controller.rb`:

```
def subject_params
  params.require(:subject).permit(:someattributes)
end
```

Comment: this still isn't working.  It makes sense to me but there must be another issue.  How do you think my routes.rb look?  Thanks for helping me out